# "Error loading 'three.js' file on a local server with Node.js: Receiving a 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to load the 'three.js' file on a local server using Node.js, but I'm getting an error "GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/three/build/three net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)". I have verified the installation of Three.js and attempted to adjust the import path in my JavaScript file, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue yet.

Steps taken:

I verified the installation of Three.js in the project using the command npm install three, which created the 'node_modules/three' folder in the project's root directory. Within this folder, the 'three.js' and 'three.min.js' files are located.

I adjusted the import path in my JavaScript file (e.g., 'main.js') using a relative path. For example:

### javascript

### import * as THREE from './node_modules/three/build/three.js';

I checked the configuration of the local server to ensure it is correctly set up to serve static files. However, I still encounter the "404 (Not Found)" error when loading the 'three.js' file.
Request for help:

I would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue and successfully loading the 'three.js' file on my local server using Node.js. What might be causing this error, and how can I overcome it?

Feel free to copy and paste this summary into your Stack Overflow post and add any additional relevant details that can help the community members better understand the problem and provide specific solutions.

Remember to provide additional information about your server configuration, file structure, and any other relevant details that can assist Stack Overflow users in gaining a better understanding of your issue and offering targeted solutions.

I hope this helps! Good luck with your Stack Overflow post. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Resolving a 404 error is not specific to three.js, but I can tell you that the file `three.js` will not `import` in a browser. Use `three.module.js`, which has proper `export` statements. For further help on your networking error, please include in your question what server you are using, what folder is assigned as the root of the server when running, and the folder hierarchy between your HTML/JS files and `node_modules`.